# How can i locate rogue DHCP servers?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I am investigating some odd behaviour on a sub-net, where host registration doesn’t list some of the IPs that some users report having. Now that I’ve seen evince, i want to passively scan for the presence of a rouge DHCP server, not listed in my domain.
How might I do that?

Or rather, are there any Linux tools to list the DCHP servers within a domain?
(I might write a script to search randomly, as I suspect the rouge DHCP server is not on all the time, or perhaps not acting as a DHCP server all the time.)

Comment: Why not block dhcp answers on the switch for anything except your allowed server port ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that seems to be rarely suggested is inspecting at one of the clients that has a bad address and looking at where it came from. For example, on a Windows client "ipconfig /all" will tell you immediately what the rogue server address was.

For long term monitoring, the check_dhcp plugin for Nagios can be set to warn if you have too many responses, or an unexpected response.

As TomTom says, most enterprisey switches can be hardened to defend against various things including rogue DHCP servers.

Comment: This in combination with the MAC address of the rogue DHCP server (gathered easily enough from an affected system) and the MAC address table of the switch should lead you to the exact switch port that the rogue DHCP server is connected to, or at the very least get you looking in the right direction in a multiple switch environment.

Answer (score 2):

## Wireshark

Try a running a protocol analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) while connected to the subnet in question.  You'll want to [filter on bootp](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DHCP) messages.

If you want to do this in a truly passive manner, you'll have to wait until a client on that subnet initiates a DHCP request, after which you'll see all of the DHCP servers listening on the subnet respond to the client.  If you don't have the patience, initiate a DHCP request on your own with a connected computer.